# Shortcut to open application from taskbar

Tags: gnome, manjaro

I switched from Gnome 38 to Gnome 42. In 38, pressing `Super+1` used to open the first application from the taskbar (Zorin taskbar). In 42, there is no taskbar present unless you go to the overview.

How can I mimic taskbar behavior without actually adding a taskbar to the desktop? I've searched in a lot of forums, but cannot find any definitive answer.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the first application is always the same, why not make a shortcut for the application itself?

Comment: If I change the order, I'll have to update the shortcuts.